# Is there a standard way to figure out a seg:off representation of a physical address in real mode?

Tags: x86, x86-16, memory-segmentation

So, I know that the physical address of segment:offset is equal to `segment * 0x10 + offset`, but how do I do that the other way around?

Like if I had an address *0x1038* what would the formula be for converting that linear physical address to a segment:offset segmented address.

Comment: You mean *real mode* segmentation?  Protected-mode segmentation uses the segment register value as an index into the GDT, and doesn't allow easy access to the segment base from the descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(it's 0x10 and not plain 10, just to make sure we are on the same page.)*

It depends on the context, there are many different ways to address the same memory location this way. In fact, there are 0x1000 (4096) ways<sup>1</sup>.

`Segment = Address >> 4`, `Offset = Address & 0xF` would be one way, `Segment = (Address & 0xF0000) >> 4`, `Offset = Address & 0xFFFF` would be another, but there are many, many more.

This is because the ranges of segment and offset in terms of bits of the final address overlap:

```
  SSSS   Segment
+  OOOO  Offset
----------------
= AAAAA  Address
```

So, the address `0x12345` could be represented by all of these segment/offset pairs:

```
0235:FFF5
0236:FFE5
0237:FFD5
...
0FFD:2375
0FFE:2365
0FFF:2355
1000:2345
1001:2335
1002:2325
1003:2315
...
1232:0025
1233:0015
1234:0005
```

Of course it's easy if you already know what the segment or the offset should be - then you can use simple algebra to calculate the other.

---

<sub>**1**: This doesn't hold true near the lower end of the address spectrum (below 0x0FFF0) where some combinations of segment and offset would result in a physical address larger than 0xFFFFF and could only be used to represent a low address if there is no active 21st address line ([A20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A20_line)), causing addresses to wrap, otherwise there would be fewer ways to represent the same address.</sub>